# React Native. Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I know that there were similar questions, but all of them didn't help.
I generate signed apk for the first time, and I get error:

```
/android/app/build/generated/res/react/release/drawable-mdpi/src_images_cancel.svg: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png
```

As I understand, Android doesn't support **svg**.  I didn't put  any **svg** to drawable-mdpi. 
I suppose that some library did it. Moreover, when I remove those svgs from the folder, those files are generated again when I generate **apk** (I do it using android studio).

As I do it in the first time, I can't understand what to do. When I use emulator, I haven't got the same error, I do not get any errors at all.
It seems, that some package uses those files, but how to understand which one?

Comment: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg/issues/239#issuecomment-286975064

Answer (score 1):

you need to store them into `drawable-nodpi` and use filename-suffix `.xml`.

it's alike a common drawable with `vector` and `path`.

Comment: I have no drawable-nodpi. Am i right, I should manually create it on the same level as drawable-mdpi and move each svg file which cause the error to that folder, and change their name like src_images_cancel.svg.xml? Then I need to generate apk again and it should help to avoid the error?

Comment: Curious thing happened... I did everything like I said in previous comment, but after start apk generation command folder was deleted and of course its content too.

Comment: I found one more thing. Problem connected to files I add to the page using "react-native-svg-uri" library.

Comment: @JohnSmith you are right about this, was the case for me also.

Comment: @JohnSmith i use the same library, how do you solve it, please?